# Hibernate CriteriaBuilder generates wrong sql output while using subquery as a selection

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria, criteriaquery

We have two related entity - **Customer** and **User**. There is OneToMany-ManyToOne relation between this entities as I added below. I'm trying to get many side(User) count while getting Customer pageable list with subquery. I saw that when I debug hibernate generates irrelevant sql output, associates join unlike subquery is.
**Entities:**

**Customer**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String code;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

---

**User**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    @Email
    private String email;

    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    private String code;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "customer_user",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")})
    private Customer customer;
```

Repository method is like below:

```
  public PageableData<List<CustomerBaseDto>> getAllCustomers(PageableBaseRequest<GetFilteredCustomers> request) {
        CriteriaQuery<CustomerBaseDto> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(CustomerBaseDto.class);
        Root<Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);

        Subquery<Long> userSubquery = query.subquery(Long.class);
        Root<User> userRoot = userSubquery.from(User.class);

        userSubquery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(userRoot.get(User_.id)))
                .where(criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.customer).get(Customer_.id), root.get(Customer_.id)));

        query.multiselect(
                root.get(BaseEntity_.id),
                root.get(BaseEntity_.enabled),
                root.get(Customer_.code),
                root.get(Customer_.email),
                root.get(Customer_.name),
                userSubquery);

        return getPageableData(request.getPageNumber(), request.getPageSize(), session, root, query);
    }
```

and sql output which hibernate does:

```
select c.id                          as customer_id,
       c.code                        as customer_code,
       c.name                        as customer_name,
       (select count(u.id)
        from users u
                 left outer join customer_user cu on u.id = cu.user_id
        where cu.customer_id = u.id) as user_count
from customer c
limit ? offset ?
```

As you see subquery where clause must be `cu.customer_id = c.id` instead of `cu.customer_id = u.id`.

---

Versions

| # | Version |
| --- | --- |
| Java | 1.8 |
| Spring Boot | 2.7.17 |
| Hibernate | 5.6.15.Final |
| Hibernate Jpamodelgen | 5.6.15.Final |

**Expected query must be like below**

```
select c.id                          as customer_id,
       c.code                        as customer_code,
       c.name                        as customer_name,
       (select count(u.id)
        from users u
                 left outer join customer_user cu on u.id = cu.user_id
        where cu.customer_id = c.id) as user_count
from customer c
limit ? offset ?
```

Comment: I believe that is a bug, however the workaround should exists: `Root< Customer> correlated = userSubquery.correlate(root); ... criteriaBuilder.equal(..., correlated.get(Customer_.id))`

Comment: FYI: you do not need to pass id attributes to query, instead of `criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.customer).get(Customer_.id), root.get(Customer_.id))` it is enough to write: `criteriaBuilder.equal(userRoot.get(User_.customer), root)`

Answer (score 0):

You can start by optimizing the target sql:

```sql
SELECT c.id AS customer_id,
       c.code AS customer_code,
       c.name AS customer_name,
       COUNT(cu.user_id) AS user_count
FROM customer c
LEFT JOIN user u ON c.id = u.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.code, c.name
LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

The next spec query implementation will be simpler:

```java
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;

private record CustomerBaseDto(Long id, String code, String name, Long userCount) {
}

@Test
void testCountSubTable() {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<CustomerBaseDto> query = cb.createQuery(CustomerBaseDto.class);
    Root<Customer> root = query.from(Customer.class);
    Join<Customer, User> join = root.join("users", JoinType.LEFT);
    query.multiselect(root.get("id"), root.get("code"), root.get("name"), cb.count(join.get("id")))
            .groupBy(root.get("id"), root.get("code"), root.get("name"));
    List<CustomerBaseDto> resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).setMaxResults(10).getResultList();
}
```

Hibernate sql output:

```sql
select c1_0.id,c1_0.code,c1_0.name,count(u1_0.user_id) from customer c1_0 left join customer_user u1_0 on c1_0.id=u1_0.customer_id group by 1,2,3 fetch first ? rows only
```

Comment: Yes, it worked this way. Also for other selections groupBy must be added. But if we need to use other methods instead of count() probably bug will pop up again.